# Bot not connecting to MS Teams Channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

MS BOT Framework bots not working on Microsoft teams channel. Its working fine on every other channel configured.

App ID: b3e237eb-7a3b-4b15-b8e1-4c30d1c94c77

code used:

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));


            if(activity.Text.ToUpper().Contains("EMAILS") || activity.Text.ToUpper().Contains("EMAIL") ||
                activity.Text.ToUpper().Contains("MAILBOX") || activity.Text.ToUpper().Contains("OUTLOOK") )
            {
                    // return our reply to the user
                    Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"blah .. blah ..");
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);

                    reply = activity.CreateReply($"blah .. blah ..");
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);

                    reply = activity.CreateReply($"blah .. blah ..");
                    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);                    }               

            }
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved after bots was enabled in the office 365 tenant administration for Microsoft Teams. 
[image]
Apparently bots until recently worked fine without this permission being set. So when MS started to enforce it, existing bots or new bots wouldn't work in Teams anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Hello:  I was able to add and test your bot to my Teams client. Per your sample, I entered "Mail" and got a response.  Are you still seeing issues on your side?

Comment: I can't get any reply from the bot mentioned by @ashwar nor can I get replies from any of my own bots. I get the following error in the chrome debugger: 

0-angular-jquery.min-7030ee74.js:121 2017-01-10T08:19:49.849Z Failed to get extension definition for given id28:b3e237eb-7a3b-4b15-b8e1-4c30d1c94c77

I get this error regardsless of which custom bot I'm trying to talk to, have tried a handful.

Comment: One more thing to check:  did you enable sideloading of Bots via the Office Admin Portal?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/setup

Comment: Wanted to follow up with both posters.  Are you seeing your bots work now?  The "enabling" requirement is something the team enforced only recently so that would explain working bots breaking.  Furthermore, we're chasing down an issue with bots built with the Node.js BotFramework SDK not working right on Teams.  Hope to have a fix soon.

Comment: Well I'm not Office 365 admin on our production tenant, where the bots were working until recently. But I can confirm that the bot works on my development tenant, so you are probably right that something have changed in the admin interface (I'm also pretty certain that our admin didn't change anything, so you must have pushed an update that wasn't backwards compatible).

Comment: One other follow-up:  the Node.JS BotFramework issue was fixed in botbuilder v3.5.4

Comment: Now I am able to add BoT to MS Teams but when I try to add this BoT into a MS Teams .. team then I am getting an error "We ran into a issue. Please try again later."

Comment: @ashwarhussain  I tried again just now and was able to add and get a response from the bot you reference above (b3e237eb-7a3b-4b15-b8e1-4c30d1c94c77)  Therefore you bot is working fine in Teams in general.  So the next step is to replicate what I did: open up a new 1-1 chat and in the To: box paste in that id.  It should resolve to the name of your bot, and you should get responses from it.  If you are trying to add a Bot to a Team via the "Add members", please note that this functionality is currently not supported, but should be soon.

Comment: This is what I was trying to get working. I was trying to add BoT to a team via "Add Members". OK, thanks for letting us know that its not possible as of now. Any tentative timeline on getting this feature implemented?

Comment: @ashwarhussain Update - bots in channels is now supported:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/botsadd